# How do I access access the value for "distance" in a Google Distance API JSON payload? (Getting KeyError)

Tags: python, json, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I'm new to using the Google Distance Matrix API, and I keep getting the following error "KeyError: 'distance'" instead of the value for the distance. All solutions to similar problems seem to conform to the code I'm using, where the first items in the lists "rows" and "elements" are accessed with the index [0], then the "distance" and "value" items are accessed like dictionaries.

Here's the relevant code block:

```
# Loop through each row in the data frame using pairwise for (i1, row1), (i2, row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):

#Assign latitude and longitude as origin/departure points
  LatOrigin = row1["latitude"]
  LongOrigin = row1["longitude"]
  origins = (LatOrigin,LongOrigin)

  #Assign latitude and longitude from the next row as the destination point
  LatDest = row2["latitude"]   # Save value as lat
  LongDest = row2["longitude"]  # Save value as lat
  destination = (LatDest,LongDest)

  #pass origin and destination variables to distance_matrix function# output in meters
  result = gmaps.distance_matrix(origins, destination, mode='walking')["rows"][0]["elements"][0]['distance']["value"]

  #append result to list
  list.append(result)
```

And here's the format of the JSON payload I expect:

```
    {
  "originAddresses": [ "Greenwich, Greater London, UK", "13 Great Carleton Square, Edinburgh, City of Edinburgh EH16 4, UK" ],
  "destinationAddresses": [ "Stockholm County, Sweden", "Dlouhá 609/2, 110 00 Praha-Staré Město, Česká republika" ],
  "rows": [ {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 70778,
        "text": "19 hours 40 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1887508,
        "text": "1173 mi"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 44476,
        "text": "12 hours 21 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1262780,
        "text": "785 mi"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 96000,
        "text": "1 day 3 hours"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 2566737,
        "text": "1595 mi"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 69698,
        "text": "19 hours 22 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1942009,
        "text": "1207 mi"
      }
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: It seems that the element [0] of "elements" does not have the key "distance". If you try with `["rows"][0]["elements"][1]['distance']["value"]`, do you get the same Error message?

Comment: @KevinQuinzel, thanks. Tried that but got IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: My bad. Just noticed that 'distance' is written with simple quotes. Do you get the same result with double quotes ["distance"]

Comment: Kevin, good catch, but that discrepancy exists because I played around with the quotes as I troubleshot. The problem persists with double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate the `"KeyError: 'distance'"` issue when my Distance Matrix request returns the `{'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'}`. Having this result shows that there's no `Distance` in the result thus it throws the KeyError. [ZERO_RESULTS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview#element-level-status-codes) indicates no route could be found between the origin and destination. Check the coordinates that you are passing, when you are getting this issue as there might be no route between these.

Here's a code snippet of the sample of Zero Result:

```
import googlemaps

LatOrigin = 0
LongOrigin = 0
origins = (LatOrigin,LongOrigin)

  #Assign latitude and longitude from the next row as the destination point
LatDest = 40.6905615
  # Save value as lat
LongDest = -73.9976592
# Save value as lat
destination = (LatDest,LongDest)

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='YOUR_KEY') 

result = gmaps.distance_matrix(origins, destination, mode='walking')
print(result)
```

You can see the KeyError when you change the result value to this: `result = gmaps.distance_matrix(origins, destination, mode='walking')["rows"][0]["elements"][0]['distance']["value"]`

Here's a sample where there's a route between coordinates thus getting the Distance value:

```
import googlemaps

LatOrigin = 40.6655101
LongOrigin = -73.89188969999998
origins = (LatOrigin,LongOrigin)

  #Assign latitude and longitude from the next row as the destination point
LatDest = 40.6905615
  # Save value as lat
LongDest = -73.9976592
# Save value as lat
destination = (LatDest,LongDest)

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='YOUR_KEY') 

result = gmaps.distance_matrix(origins, destination, mode='walking')["rows"][0]["elements"][0]['distance']["value"]
print('distance',result)
```